# Speaker not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-ace

My phone has been working fine but since a few days ago I noticed that the speaker doesn't work on SMS notifications and music. In order for it to work, I must insert and remove headset jack. But when I restart the phone it doesn't work again so I have to insert/remove the headset jack everytime. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What Cyanogenmod version are you using?

Comment: @DanHulme  cm-7-20130301-NIGHTLY-cooper

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a bug in the ROM you're using. Cyanogenmod nightly builds are unstable and often have missing functionality: they're not recommended for everyday use, only for testing. Try updating your ROM to a more stable build of Cyanogenmod, if one is available.